# x86 assembly - MASM32 - multiplying 3 numbers

Tags: assembly, masm32

I have a program that multiplies 3 numbers and i am trying to understand. I have some questions and i am hoping someone can explain whats going on with the program and tell me if i am on the right track. I understand i have more than one question so i am sorry about that.

```
.data?
  num1 dd ?
  num2 dd ?
  num3 dd ?

.data
sum dd 0
prod dd 0

.code

start:



main proc


mov EAX, sval(input("Enter a number: "))
mov num1, EAX
mov EAX, sval(input("Enter a number: "))
mov num2, EAX
mov EAX, sval(input("Enter a number: "))
mov num3, EAX





mov EAX, num1
mov EBX, num2
mul BL                 

mov EBX, num3
mul BX              

mov prod, EDX
```

this has me confused...

```
mov EBX, num3
mul BX
```

so, we are storing num3 into BL?
but since the result of num1 and num2 is 16 bit and stored into AX
we mul BX? instead of BL? but isnt num3 in BL?

im sorry there isnt one specific question. If my logic is incorrect or close can you explain whats going on piece by piece and why?

Thank you

Comment: This code definitely doesn't "multiply 3 numbers", it does something weird and confusing. Why not use `IMUL`?

Comment: It actually does work even with the worst case scenerio multiplying by 255

Comment: So it's actually "enter a number *between 0 and 255*"? Otherwise there's just no way it's going to work.

Comment: If you add any number between 0 - 255 it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do an 8-bit multiplication like `mul bl`, it takes `al`, multiplies it by the specified input, and puts the result in `ax`.

When you do a 16-bit multiplication like `mul bx`, it takes `ax`, multiplies it by the specified input, and puts the result in `dx:ax` (i.e., the 16 most significant bits of the result in `dx`, and the 16 least significant bits of the result in `ax`).

(Just for completeness): if you do a 32-bit multiplication like `mul ebx`, it multiplies `eax` by `ebx`, and puts the result in `edx:eax` (offhand I don't remember for sure, but I'd guess 64-bit multiplication works about the same way).

As far as `BL` vs. `BX` goes (or `AL`/`AH`/`AX`, etc.), what you have aren't really separate registers -- `AL` is really the 8 least significant bits of `AX`. `AH` is the 8 most significant bits of AX. BL is the 8 least significant bits of BX, and BH is the 8 most significant bits of BX (and so on for CL/CH/DL/DH).

For example, if you execute code like:

```
xor bx, bx
mov bl, 1
```

BH will then equal 0 (set to zero by the `xor bx, bx`), BL will equal 1 (set by the mov) and bx will also equal 1 (because it now contains the bit pattern 00000000 00000001).

Comment: if i was to add one more number would that be a 32-bit multiplication? if so then the result would be in edx:eax? would i then shift eax into edx?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for 64-bit. `rdx:rax`