# Assembly language - masm32 - multiplying

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am multiplying 3 numbers which works good even with a carry. I want to add a 4th number to multiply just for learning purposes.

After i multiply 3 numbers i shift into EDX and print. Works great.
After i add a 4th number i think i am multiplying 32bit x 32bit? So it stores into EDX:EAX?

Would i then need to shift EAX into EDX so they are together to print?
Im not sure if i am doing it right for the 4th number?

```
.data?
  num1 dd ?
  num2 dd ?
  num3 dd ?
  num4 dd ?

.data
sum dd 0
prod dd 0
prod2 dd 0
```

here are the prompts

```
mov EAX, sval(input("Enter first number: "))
mov num1, EAX
mov EAX, sval(input("Enter second number: "))
mov num2, EAX
mov EAX, sval(input("Enter third number: "))
mov num3, EAX

mov EAX, sval(input("Enter fourth number: "))
mov num4, EAX
```

here is the logic

```
mov EAX, num1
mov EBX, num2
mul BL                 ; 8 bit x 8 bit ----> AX / 16bit

mov EBX, num3
mul BX     ; 16bit x 16bit --->DX:AX

shl EDX, 16  ; shift low to high             ;high / low in EDX
mov DX, AX     ; mov in all reg

mov ECX, num4   ; 32bit x 32bit ---> EDX:EAX
mul CX
mov prod2, EAX  ; for printing
```

I am not sure if i should move num4 into ECX and multiplying by CX
Should i be multiplying by 32bit instead? What am i doing wrong for the 4th number?
Thank you

Comment: Is this any different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488381/x86-assembly-masm32-multiplying-3-numbers)?

Comment: My previous post was different. My side question is the same.

Comment: Is my num4 multiplication correct? If so, how would i go about handling EDX:EAX so i can print it out correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32-bit multiplication uses `EAX` register. Your code for the third multiplication is 16-bit since your `MUL` operand uses 16-bit register, so the multiplication is `AX x CX`. 32-bit multiplication needs 32-bit operand, so in your code, you need to use `ECX` rather than `CX`. Also, the preparation for 32-bit multiplication is incomplete, since the value is still placed in `EDX` register.

So the code should be like this:

```
mov EAX, num1
mov EBX, num2
mul BL         ; 8 bit x 8 bit ---> AX / 16bit

mov EBX, num3
mul BX         ; 16bit x 16bit ---> DX:AX

shl EDX, 16    ; shift low to high  ;high / low in EDX
mov DX, AX     ; mov in all reg
mov EAX, EDX   ; prepare EAX for 32bit x32bit

mov ECX, num4
mul ECX        ; 32bit x 32bit ---> EAX x ECX ---> EDX:EAX
mov prod2, EAX ; for printing
```

Be aware that 32-bit multiplication might result a 64-bit value in `EDX:EAX`, so make sure the `EDX` register is taken into account by your *printing* function.