# Multiplication Problems in MASM32

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Hi. I am currently using MASM32 and am having some trouble multiplying things. I read the documentation and it makes no sense on why its not working.

```
    mov eax, input("X coordinate: ")
    mov ebx, input("Y coordinate: ")
    imul ebx, eax

    mov x, ebx
    print x
```

It should multiply the contents of `ebx` and `eax` and store the result in `ebx`, but it doesn't. Say you put in a 3 and a 6─all it prints is the 6.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513381/assembly-language-masm32-multiplying)?

Comment: @iTech that question pertains to `mul`. This question pertains to `imul`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Intel documentation, when multiplying two 32-bit registers, the result is stored in the register combination `edx:eax`, which represents the 64-bit product. This is implemented even in x86-64 processors, for compatibility reasons, because during the time of creation, Intel processors only supported 32-bits.

First of all, in your code, you are printing `ebx` and not `eax`, which was expected on your part even if you lack knowledge of Intel documentary. This is the reason why your code is only printing 6, as 6 was the multiplicand in `ebx`. However, to achieve the correct answer, you still must only print `edx:eax`.

So, to fix this, you must either shorten the size of the multiplier and multiplicand to 16 bits (recommended way), or, find a way to print the entirety of `edx:eax` (may prove difficult depending on library imports).

Hope this helps.